# Quem implementa as interfaces de Repository do Spring?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Temos a interface `JpaRepository` que podemos utilizar a partir da sua importação com:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
```

A partir dela temos os métodos padrões para usarmos, como o `findAll()`. Também conseguimos criar novos métodos somente colocando a assinatura, por exemplo o `findByPessoaName(String nome);`

Mas quem realiza toda a implementação dessa interface `JpaRepository`  e desses outros métodos que coloco apenas a assinatura e o Spring gera de forma automática? É o Hibernate (supondo que estou utilizando ele) ou o próprio Spring Data? Sei que o Spring Data JPA utiliza o Hibernate como a implementação da especificação JPA por padrão, mas o próprio Hibernate sabe implementar esses métodos padrões?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

São as *annotations* do Spring que fazem a mágica.

Quando tu usas o `@Autowired`, o Spring localiza a tua interface, cria 1 classe e implementa tudo.

Isso tudo é feito com *annotations* e *reflection*.